# console.writeline not displaying list elements

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am an absolute begginer to c#, I'm stuck on my first console app on something very basic, but I can't get past it.

I want to be able to take a users input, write it to a list, and have the elements in the list displayed back to me.

This is how I have created my list, as I understand it, it is initilised with no values in it.

```
class PersonRegistry
    {
        // Create a registry of Persons
        public static List<Person> Registry = new List<Person>();
    }
```

I've constructed my person class:

```
class Person
    {
        private Guid Guid {get; set;}
        private string FirstName {get; set;}
        private string LastName {get; set;}
        private double SalaryPerHour {get; set;}
        private double SalaryPerDay {get; set;}
        private double RechargePerHour {get; set;}
        private double RechargePerDay {get; set;}

       public Person(string firstName, string lastName, double salaryPerHour, double salaryPerDay, double rechargePerHour, double rechargePerDay)
        {
            this.Guid = new Guid();  // set Guid when object is created
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.SalaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
            this.SalaryPerDay = salaryPerDay;
            this.RechargePerHour = rechargePerHour;
            this.RechargePerDay = rechargePerDay;
        }
    }
```

I accept user input:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main() 
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your salary per hour");
            double salaryPerHour = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your salary per day");
            double salaryPerDay = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your recharge per hour");
            double rechargePerHour = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your recharge per day");
            double rechargePerDay = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

And here is where I am writing to the list:

```
            PersonRegistry.Registry.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, salaryPerHour, salaryPerDay, rechargePerHour, rechargePerDay));
```

I tried this first to then have the program print the elements in the list, but which didn't work:

```
            //PersonRegistry.Registry.ForEach(Console.WriteLine); - doesn't work as expected, us for loop?
```

And then I tried using a for loop, which also doesn;t work:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < PersonRegistry.Registry.Count; i++)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(PersonRegistry.Registry[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding _but which didn't work_? What output did you see in the console?

Comment: Debug the code and check are you getting the PersonRegistry when you are writing this: PersonRegistry.Registry.Add(new Person(firstName, lastName, salaryPerHour, salaryPerDay, rechargePerHour, rechargePerDay));

Comment: Wow that was quick. @RichardEv - yes fair comment. In the console I was able to enter the values for the parameters (first name, last name, salary etc). And then the console just terminated.

Comment: This is how the console works - it will close (if started from a debug session) when your program exits. Suggest adding [`Console.ReadKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1) at the end of your `Main` method...

Comment: @RohanRao - I set a breakpoint on that line of code and hit start debugging, but the console only allows me enter the value for the first parameter. After that.... nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all change your Person class' properties to public so you can access them.

```
class Person
{
    public Guid Guid {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public double SalaryPerHour {get; set;}
    public double SalaryPerDay {get; set;}
    public double RechargePerHour {get; set;}
    public double RechargePerDay {get; set;}

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, double salaryPerHour, double salaryPerDay, double rechargePerHour, double rechargePerDay)
    {
        this.Guid = new Guid();  // set Guid when object is created
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.SalaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
        this.SalaryPerDay = salaryPerDay;
        this.RechargePerHour = rechargePerHour;
        this.RechargePerDay = rechargePerDay;
    }
}
```

Second is, you are trying to print the object, not the properties.

```
  Console.WriteLine(PersonRegistry.Registry[i]); // this is a Person object you are trying to print.
```

---

```
 foreach(var person in PersonRegistry.Registry) {
  Console.WriteLine($ "FirstName: {person.FirstName}");
  Console.WriteLine($ "LastName: {person.LastName}");
  Console.WriteLine($ "SalaryPerHour: {person.SalaryPerHour}");
  Console.WriteLine($ "SalaryPerDay: {person.SalaryPerDay}");
  Console.WriteLine($ "RechargePerDay: {person.RechargePerDay}");
 }

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Or if you want it in a more dynamic way, than you can use like below:

```
 foreach(var person in PersonRegistry.Registry) {
  Type t = person.GetType(); // Where person is object whose properties you need.
  PropertyInfo[] pi = t.GetProperties();
  foreach(PropertyInfo p in pi) {
   System.Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + p.GetValue(person));
  }
 }

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override ToString method in Person class

```
class PersonRegistry
{
    public static List<Person> Registry = new List<Person>();

    static void AddPersonToRegistry()
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name");
        person.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your last name");
        person.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your salary per hour");
       person.SalaryPerHour = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your salary per day");
        person. SalaryPerDay = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your recharge per hour");
        person.RechargePerHour = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your recharge per day");
        person.RechargePerDay = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Registry.Add(person);
    }

    static void PrintRegistry()
    {
        Registry.ForEach(element =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
        });
    }
}

class Person
{

    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double SalaryPerHour { get; set; }
    public double SalaryPerDay { get; set; }
    public double RechargePerHour { get; set; }
    public double RechargePerDay { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, double salaryPerHour, double salaryPerDay, double rechargePerHour, double rechargePerDay)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.SalaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
        this.SalaryPerDay = salaryPerDay;
        this.RechargePerHour = rechargePerHour;
        this.RechargePerDay = rechargePerDay;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(Id)}: {Id}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(FirstName)}: {FirstName}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(LastName)}: {LastName}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(SalaryPerHour)}: {SalaryPerHour}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(SalaryPerDay)}: {SalaryPerDay}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(RechargePerHour)}: {RechargePerHour}{Environment.NewLine}" +
            $"{nameof(RechargePerDay)}: {RechargePerDay}";
    }

}
```

**References**

[Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)
[Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)
[override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)